# How to prevent people from accessing OpenShift web apps?

Tags: openshift

I just uploaded a Wildfly web application to my free OpenShift account so my team members can check it out.  It's a work in progress so I don't want people to know and access it via the web. If I want someone to use it then I'll send them the URL "XXX-XXX.rhcloud.com"

Is there a way to prevent people from knowing and accessing my web application on OpenShift?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) in order to anyone provides login/password before access your contents.

In openshift there is a enviroment variable called $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR, is the path of your working directory i.e. `/var/lib/openshift/myuserlongid/app-root/runtime/repo/`

I create a new enviroment variable called SECURE wrapping the folder path.

```
rhc set-env SECURE=/var/lib/openshift/myuserlongid/app-root/data --app myappname
```

Finally I connect to my app with ssh

```
rhc ssh myappname
```

And create the .htpasswd file

```
htpasswd -c $SECURE/.htpasswd <username>
```

**Note: The -c option to htpasswd creates a new file, overwriting any existing htpasswd file. If your intention is to add a new user to an existing htpasswd file, simply drop the -c option.**

.htaccess file

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication"
AuthUserFile ${SECURE}/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you configure openshift so that url is private, however I am sure you can hack your way. Instead of hosting your app at `"XXX-XXX.rhcloud.com`", you can set root-url of your app to be "`XXX-XXX.rhcloud.com/some_hash`" (for ex: `XXX-XXX.rhcloud.com/2d6541ff807c289fc686ad64f10509e0e74ba0be22b0462aa0ac3a7a54dd20073101ddd5843144b9a9ee83d0ba882f35d49527e3e762162f76cfd04d355411f1` )

When it comes people finding your website on search engines you can block crawlers with robot.txt or noindex meta tag. You can further read about them [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en) and [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en)